# can't import Antd stylesheet file and Webpack gives error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

When I import

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

these lines I got error like below.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 13:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders.
| /* stylelint-disable */
| /* stylelint-disable declaration-bang-space-before,no-duplicate-selectors,string-no-newline 
  */
> [class^=ant-]::-ms-clear,
| [class*= ant-]::-ms-clear,
| [class^=ant-] input::-ms-clear,
@ ./src/index.tsx 4:0-28
```

Anyone please help me how to avoid this. I am using Antd for React, Typescript project with Webpack and Babel.

Comment: Do you have loaders to parse the css file ?

Comment: yes.I have installed css-loader. WebPack Config is  {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'styles')],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },

Comment: can you add your webpack config as well ?

Comment: Okay your config says use this css-loader when you are importing any files with the extension .css | .scss from the folders `src` and `styles` . But here you using the file from your node_modules .

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: You can try the approaches suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518277/import-css-from-node-modules-in-webpack

Comment: I tried that but that also gives error

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I had done like this. please refer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590256/15375315

Answer (score -1):

import this one instead with `min.css` extension`antd/dist/antd.min.css`

Comment: This does not work